# can't display items in a desired category (V1.9.0.1, Modern Theme)

Tags: magento-1.9

After installed the recent security patches, the items in a desired category can't display on the home page using the below code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home_list" category_id="73" template="catalog/product/myhome_list.phtml"}}
```

any solution for it?

Comment: what happens when you use that code?

Comment: which security patch did you installed ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the block to the whitelist. Go to System -> Permissions -> Blocks and add `catalog/product_list` there.

Comment: can you mark it as answered then? thanks :)